# Flow crashing on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, windows, flowtype

Version 0.74.0

Crashes on any flow command with error:

```
Fatal error: exception Unix.Unix_error(62, "socketpair", "")
```

Other repositories on my machine using flow work fine, as did this project until recently (i.e. I did not change the version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by a firewall setting.